# How to decide which files from iCloud Drive are stored on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, icloud

I recently looked into the composition of the files stored on my iPhone (XS, 64GB internal storage capacity, iOS 14.0, Apple Family Sharing activated with iCloud 200 GB storage plan).

Since I have almost depleted the free storage capacity of my iPhone, I wanted to do some optimisations and saw that 1.5 GB was taken by iCloud Drive. I have roughly 58/64GB used in total.

As I understood, ‘iCloud Drive’ as mentioned in the ‘iPhone storage’ overview (settings > general > iPhone storage) comprises of all files I have saved in my iCloud which are downloaded onto my phone.

Currently I have 13GB of files in my iCloud (ie what is shown at iCloud > manage storage > iCloud Drive).

I know that the most recent files I have used of iCloud Drive are stored on my iPhone. But how can I decide which ones to keep there? Can’t I manage which files to always keep on my phone and maybe even limit how much in total can be saved by iCloud Drive on my phone?

Answer (score 1):

Folder or file level of granularity is not available today in iOS iCloud settings or Files apps.